# Filling a polygon in GDI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, gdi

I got a self drawn polygon (4 points and lineto(), polygon() doesn't work because it leaves marks when I move the polygon on screen) which needs to be filled. 
Can anyone help me?

Here is my function DrawHand

```
void CClock::DrawHand (CDC* pDC, int nLength, int nScale, int nDegrees, COLORREF clrColor)
    {
        CPoint point[4];
        double nRadians = (double) nDegrees * 0.017453292;

        point[0].x = (int) (nLength * sin (nRadians));
        point[0].y = (int) (nLength * cos (nRadians));

        point[2].x = -point[0].x / nScale;
        point[2].y = -point[0].y / nScale;

        point[1].x = -point[2].y;
        point[1].y = point[2].x;

        point[3].x = -point[1].x;
        point[3].y = -point[1].y;

        CPen pen (PS_SOLID, 0, clrColor);
        CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject (&pen);

            pDC->MoveTo(point[0]);
        pDC->LineTo(point[1]);
        pDC->LineTo(point[2]);
        pDC->LineTo(point[3]);
        pDC->LineTo(point[0]);

            pDC->SelectObject (pOldPen);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have so far?

Comment: @alfonso I have included it in my question now.

Comment: Got it now. I made a Polygon(). Did this previously but gave the brush a false parameter. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the polygon "leaves marks" when moved is because you don't clear the background when you redraw. Start by drawing a rectangle with the background color.